# My Kotlin app closes just after opening, after after for locations permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3, android-jetpack-compose

I have written a Kotlin application wherein we get the map zoomed to the user's current location. The problem is, the application closes as soon as it is opened. The app does not crash in case of emulator, but does so when run on a physical device. In emulator, the output is a blank screen.I have attached the MainActivity file below:

```
package com.shuklansh.mapsalphaproject

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMap

import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalSoftwareKeyboardController
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places
import com.google.maps.android.compose.*
import com.shuklansh.mapsalphaproject.ui.theme.MapsAlphaProjectTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1234
    }

    private val locationPermissionGranted = mutableStateOf(false)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API_KEY_HERE")

        setContent {
            getLocationPermission()
            if (locationPermissionGranted.value) {
                MapScreen()
            }else{
                Text("Need permission")
            }
        }
    }


    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode== PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationPermissionGranted.value=true
        }
    }

    private fun getLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            locationPermissionGranted.value = true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }

}
@Composable
fun MapScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val fusedLocationProviderClient =
        remember { LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context) }

    var lastKnownLocation by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Location?>(null)
    }

    var deviceLatLng by remember {
        mutableStateOf(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
    }

    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(deviceLatLng, 18f)
    }

    val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
    locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(context as MainActivity) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
            lastKnownLocation = task.result
            deviceLatLng = LatLng(lastKnownLocation!!.latitude, lastKnownLocation!!.longitude)
            cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(deviceLatLng, 18f)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
        }
    }

    GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        MarkerInfoWindowContent(
            state = MarkerState(
                position = deviceLatLng
            )
        ) { marker ->
            Text(marker.title ?: "You", color = Color.Red)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The program happens to ask for location permissions before closing for the first time. The rest of the time, it just closes after opening. There are no problems in the terminal, but the app keeps on crashing. I can't seem to understand the problem behind this.
In the emulator, the app does not crash, but does not seem to show the map, and shows a blank screen. Have been searching the internet for this, but to no answers.

Comment: please post your ADB logs for the crash

Comment: Hey, I am new to this. ADB I am looking at is actually very large. Is it actually the one?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code except "lastKnownLocation!!". Verify null check before using it.

Comment: Thanks so much @AbdullahJaved. This was to the point

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this permission `android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` ??

Also try to call this from onCreate()

```
    private fun getLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        locationPermissionGranted.value = true
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this didn't work. It continues to crash.
Also, I had specified the fine location permission in manifest file